# Javascript библиотека для рисования графиков функций

Tags: график, javascript, библиотеки

Здравствуйте!

Нужна библиотека на js (в проекте уже прикручен Jquery) для рисования графиков функций. Конкретнее - кривые второго порядка в каноническом виде.

Нужно:

- Работать в нескольких системах координат, одна - родительская, остальные - сдвинуты относительно родительской на (xn, yn) и повернуты на некоторый угол (чего нигде найти не могу).
- Рисовать графики функций в каждой системе отдельно, желательно разными цветами.
- Очень хочется возможность удобно перемещать полотно и масштабировать его.

Comment: http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/examples/ 
Эту смотрели?

Comment: @Genson, да, смотрел. Там разве можно создавать несколько систем координат?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Весьма рекомендую вот это: [Attractive JavaScript plotting for jQuery](http://www.flotcharts.org/)

Мне здоровски помогла в свое время, умеет складывать графики, но насчет масштабирования и перемещения - вряд-ли, разве что самому дописать обертку для этого, но отжирать будет ресурсы при большом количестве графики

Comment: Ух ты! Выглядит круто, пойду читать документацию. Масштабирование: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/navigate/index.html

Comment: Ну.. под конкретную задачу он не подходит, но все равно буду иметь ввиду: хорошая штука.

Answer (score 0):

Еще одна графическая библиотека [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/), ориентированная правда скорее на интерактивность (анимации и отклик на действия пользователя). К тому же есть возможность импорта изображений из файла